# When selected option from dropdown then how to hide that selected option into another dropdown using jQuery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, drop-down-menu

```js
<select>
  <option value = "volvo" > Volvo < /option> 
  <option value = "saab" > Saab < /option> 
  <option value = "vw" > VW < /option> 
  <option value = "audi"> Audi < /option> 
</select>
```

I am having many dropdown where all dropdown having same option value but when user select option then that selected value should hide or remove in others dropdown and if user changes option that that previous selected option should come into that option and currently selected option should hide into other dropdown.
when selected option from dropdown then how to hide that selected option into another dropdown.I tried to find solution of this but no one's code working properly.

Answer (score 0):

3 select boxes:

```
<select id="1">
  <option value = "volvo" > Volvo </option> 
  <option value = "saab" > Saab </option> 
  <option value = "vw" > VW </option> 
  <option value = "audi"> Audi </option> 
</select>
<select id="2">
  <option value = "volvo" > Volvo </option> 
  <option value = "saab" > Saab </option> 
  <option value = "vw" > VW </option> 
  <option value = "audi"> Audi </option> 
</select>
<select id="3">
  <option value = "volvo" > Volvo </option> 
  <option value = "saab" > Saab </option> 
  <option value = "vw" > VW </option> 
  <option value = "audi"> Audi </option> 
</select>
```

Your js code:

```
m_val="";
m_text="";
$(document).ready(function(){
  val = $("select:first").val();
  text = $("select:first option:selected").text();
  $("select:not(:first) option[value='"+val+"']").remove();

  m_val=val;
  m_text=text;

  $("select").change(function(){
    val = $(this).val();
    id = $(this).attr("id");
    text = $(this).text();

    $("select[id!='"+id+"'] option[value='"+val+"']").remove();

    $("select").each(function( index ) {
      i = $(this).attr("id");
      if($("select[id='"+i+"'] option[value='"+m_val+"']").length==0){
        $(this).append("<option value = '"+m_val+"' > "+m_text+"</option> ");
      }
    });

    m_val=val;
    m_text=text;
  });
});
```

Here is a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1krwzL4j/

Comment: You might want to check where you are adding back the previously removed item. In your fiddle, it creates an option tag with text for all the other option elements.

Comment: You are right. I did not read the requirements carfully enough.

Answer (score 0):

Add event handler to the select boxes then find the other select boxes and remove the appropriate option elements. Also, store the selected value as data so we can put it back;

```js
$("select").change(function(){
  var selVal = $(this).val();
  var prevVal = $(this).data("selVal");
  
  if(selVal !== prevVal)
  {
      //Take out the new select
      $("select").not(this).find("option[value='" + selVal + "']").remove();
  
      //Store selcted val so we can put it back
      $(this).data("selVal", selVal);
      
      //Get the previously selected option... clone it and append it to the others
      var newOption = $(this).find("option[value='" + prevVal + "']").clone();
      $("select").not(this).append(newOption);      
  }  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option value = "volvo" > Volvo </option> 
  <option value = "saab" > Saab </option> 
  <option value = "vw" > VW </option> 
  <option value = "audi"> Audi </option> 
</select>

<select>
  <option value = "volvo" > Volvo </option> 
  <option value = "saab" > Saab </option> 
  <option value = "vw" > VW </option> 
  <option value = "audi"> Audi </option> 
</select>
<select>
  <option value = "volvo" > Volvo </option> 
  <option value = "saab" > Saab </option> 
  <option value = "vw" > VW </option> 
  <option value = "audi"> Audi </option> 
</select>
<select>
  <option value = "volvo" > Volvo </option> 
  <option value = "saab" > Saab </option> 
  <option value = "vw" > VW </option> 
  <option value = "audi"> Audi </option> 
</select>
```